# change variable with click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

After a exhaustive research in stackoverflow, i did not found any solution for my question, and im obliged to open a new thread.
I have a chart based in highcharts, working with json file. However I have 3 different json files that I want make it changeable with a click.
In short: When click in button "day" I want that $getJSON file "./json/historyday.json". When I click in month, I want $getJSON file "./json/historymonth.json".
please find my code below:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>



<input type="button" id="hour" value="hour" />
<input type="button" id="day" value="day" />


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 900px"></div> 
<script>

// file change with click
var filejson = './json/historyday.json'; 

$('#hour').click(function (){
   var filejson = '../json/historyday.json';
});
$('#day').click(function (){
    var filejson = '../json/historymonth.json';
});


$.getJSON(filejson, function (data) {

 var currentValue = (data[data.length - 1][1]);

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
       enabled: false
     },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Exchange rate'
          },
          
          plotLines: [{
                value: currentValue,
                color: 'green',
                dashStyle: 'solid',
                width: 2,
                label: {
                    text: currentValue + 'EUR'
                }
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
            type: 'areaspline',
            threshold: null,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you've not added any click listeners ?

Comment: your scrip will run just first time after page loads. look into click listeners etc first

Comment: no, I need help to implant that in my script, for that reason my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle request and update the highchart based on clicked button using data-bind. I have uploaded it to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jehadnasser/4pnxvqrh/) too,

**Update** (automatic reload every time-interval): [with-auto-reload-feature-jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jehadnasser/fugzqx2p/6/)

```js
// Draw Highchart
function drawHighchart(timeFrameUrl) {
    $.ajax({url: timeFrameUrl, success: function(result) {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            xAxis: {
            },
            series: [{
                data: result    
            }]
        });
    }});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedTimeFrameUrl = null;

    // Draw default on ready
    selectedTimeFrameUrl = $("#day").data("url");
    drawHighchart(selectedTimeFrameUrl);

    // Draw based on clicked button
    $("#month, #day, #hour").click(function() {
        selectedTimeFrameUrl = $(this).data("url");
        drawHighchart(selectedTimeFrameUrl);
    });

    // Reload selected TimeFrame data every 5 minutes
    setInterval(function() {
        drawHighchart(selectedTimeFrameUrl);
    }, 300000);// 5 minutes === 300000 ms
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<button id="month" data-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/12at1e">Month</button>
<button id="day" data-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/16cjya">Day</button>
<button id="hour" data-url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fecci">Hour</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Works prefectly. WIll be good if you can put the reload data also :D

Comment: you mean reload(refresh) button?

Comment: No, I want make it auto reload(refresh) 5 in 5 min

Comment: Updated: Added automatic reload every time-interval;

Comment: I just updated the script before your post fix :(
The auto reload is working, but when I click in some Buttons, the Json file reload multi times . http://sc.sny.pt/sTcH Please see the demo jsfiddle. Can you try help me with this?
https://jsfiddle.net/xL5gthyb/5/

Comment: when you click a button it will trigger --> drawHighchart() --> this function has "setInterval()" on Line 40 --> this setInterval executed every 1000ms(1 second-see Line 75) --> and drawHighchart again and again and again....
Please note that setInterval() executed forever not only once like setTimeout()

Comment: @JahadNasser I konw, I changed to 1000 just for test. Running my script here http://jsfiddle.net/xL5gthyb/5 you will see that when I click in each button, will multiply the requests.  See this image sc.sny.pt/sTcH 
In short, after click will reload the file associated to that click + last json. if you click 2x the script will load last json + last click json file + recent click json file. Just test using my script please. I think that the problem is that I do not have a " var selectedTimeFrameUrl = null;"  I have no idea where can I apply the null.

Comment: Guys, any possibility to apply cookies on click?

Comment: Hi, sure you can, as I am busy try to post another question so you can get help faster. BTW this is how to use cookies with JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code inside a function, to which you can pass the filename of the JSON data you want it to load.  Then you can call that function with a different filename from each button's click handler:

```js
var drawChart = function(filejson) {
  console.log("Get data for ", filejson);
  $.getJSON(filejson, function(data) {
    // ... your code to draw the chart here
  });
}

$('#day').on("click", function() {
  drawChart("./json/historyday.json");
});
$('#month').on("click", function() {
  drawChart("./json/historymonth.json");
});
$('#hour').on("click", function() {
  drawChart("./json/historyhour.json");
});

// Draw one of them by default:
drawChart("./json/historyday.json");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="month" value="month" />
<input type="button" id="day" value="day" />
<input type="button" id="hour" value="hour" />

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 900px"></div>
```

What you're currently trying to do in those click handlers (at least in the latest edit to the question) just changes the contents of the `filejson` variable; that won't do anything visible because the ajax call and actually drawing the chart still needs to be triggered as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly.. thanks a lot :)
What about default value? Because chart will only works with a click, I want it load at first time with day.json then make the options clickable.

Comment: I updated the answer: for the default display on page load, you can just call the same function directly.

Answer (score 0):

var filePath= {"day":"pathTodayJSON",
        "month":"pathMonthJson",
         "hour":"pathHoutJson"}

Then call filePath.day, filePath.month,filePath.hour